# Eclipse segfaults when autocompleting code in maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, fedora, surefire

I am working with Eclipse and maven in a project, and since my last system update or so, each time I use the code fixing tools (Ctrl.+1) eclipse segfaults.

The abrt log saved by Fedora contains the following stacktrace:

```
Uncaught java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception in thread "main" in a method java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass() with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .home.username.workspace.ibei.target.surefire.surefirebooter1921570312357618538.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader$1.class]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader$1.class]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/security/AccessController.class]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader.class]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/ClassLoader.class]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader.class]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/ClassLoader.class]
```

It seems as if the surefire plugin for maven wouldn't load java.lang.String, what is it wrong?

I've tried using the OpenJDK at Java versions 1.7.0 and 1.8.0, and reinstalling eclipse and maven a bunch of times.

Comment: That shows a stack trace, not a seg fault.  What evidence do you have of a segfault?

Comment: Fedora's "Automatic reports" (abtr-applet) that says "Process /usr/lib/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin/java was killed by signal 11 (SIGSEGV)"

Comment: A segfault would indicate a bug in the JVM or some native code. If your project does not include native code, it is someone else's problem.

Comment: I think the weirdest thing here is that the JVM can actually throw a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for something in the java.lang package. Or maybe I'm misinterpreting the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing google-talkplugin if you have one. It's faulty and breaks webkit, causing crashes on every browser show (code assist is browser based).

Comment: wow, this seemed like a shot in the dark, but looks like in my case this was exactly the problem. I had installed google-talkplugin recently, then Eclipse started behaving like this. Wouldn't have guessed that these two might be interfering...